# Make a bunch of JLabel 's' invisible

Tags: java, swing, visibility, jlabel

I have 8 `JLabels` that i initially want to be invisible . The `jlabels` start from 25 and go 32. `_(i.e jLabel25 ---> jLabel32)_` Instead of making them invisible one by one i was thinking of using a for loop that could make them invisible by following these lines of code :

```
for( int i = 25 ; i <= 32 ; i++ ) {
        jLabel(i).setVisible(false);
}
```

But i get an obvious error that says **"Cannot find symbol , method--> jLabel(int) "**

What should i do to avoid *writing 8 statements* asking to make each `label` invisible ?

Comment: Do not number your variable names. Give them meaningful names so when you or someone see the code later, it will make sense. Also, if you have 32 labels, it might be an indication that your design is not well encapsulated. You can make sub-panels for sections of the main form and this will also make working with the code easier.

Comment: simple mistake `for( int i = 25 ; i <= 32 ; i++ ) {` must be `for( int i = 25 ; i < 32 ; i++ ) {` nothing else

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the labels into a common collection, and iterate through that.

```
Collection<JLabel> myLabels = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
myLabels.add(jLabel25); // .. and so on

for (JLabel label : myLabels) {
   label.setVisible(false);
}
```

Comment: Don't you think writing eight statements `jLabel25.setVisible(false)..` is much easier than this !

Comment: @suhail Gupta, its all the same but with the list, you have more control to set them as visible again or add other labels to the list

Answer (score 2):

No, I do not  think that is possible, you will have to write the full name out each time:

```
jLabel25.setVisible(false);
```

Another possible solution is put the labels in a array or list, and iterate through the list/array and set it to false.

```
for(JLabel label :listOfLabels)
{
  label.setVisible(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you put them in a List?

```
List<JLabel> labels = Arrays.asList(jLabel25, jLabel26, /*rest of 'em here*/);
for(JLabel label : labels) {
    label.setVisible(false);
}
```

Comment: Yes. Duh. Oh, wait. Was that a rhetorical question?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convince your co-workers you're mad or would rather be programming in another language, you could use reflection.

```
for(Field labelField : getClass().getFields()) {
    String name = label.getName();
    if(name.startsWith("jLabel") && name.length == 8 && indexBetween(name.substring(7, 9), 25, 32)) {
        JLabel label = (JLabel) labelField.get(this);
        label.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

This only works if the labels are fields on the current class, obviously.

Comment: the important part is the very first line (not from the code, from the answer)!